# Getting line items in Drupal Commerce after checkout

Tags: php, drupal

I am writing some code to access line item information after checkout, specifically in `hook_commerce_checkout_complete()`.

When I run the following code in Devel (/devel/php) it works great, loading all line items from the order into the `$products` array. However inside the hook it throws an error the first attempt to access line item data.

```
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
  $products = array();

  foreach ($wrapper->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {
     $product = array();
     $product['quantity'] = number_format($line_item_wrapper->quantity->value());
     $product['sku'] = $line_item_wrapper->line_item_label->value();
     $product['path'] = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_display_path->value();
     $product['price'] = "$".number_format($line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price->amount->value() / 100, 2);
     $product['title'] = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->title->value();
     $product['image'] = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->field_image->value();
     array_push($products, $product);
  }
```

I tried loading the order with `commerce_order_load($order->order_id)` but the returning object was no different from the $order param. Also, the wrapper object for the order inside the hook is not as large as the wrapper object I got using Devel.

More info: I’m on Commerce Kickstart 2.0. Also, for caching we’re using Varnish. The exact error I’m getting is:
See accuair_checkout_commerce_checkout_complete()

```
# 0 /srv/bindings/41e74e13d874402496da2dafa0aea98b/code/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc(392): EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo('commerce_produc…')
# 1 /srv/bindings/41e74e13d874402496da2dafa0aea98b/code/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc(413): EntityStructureWrapper->get('commerce_produc…')
# 2 /srv/bindings/41e74e13d874402496da2dafa0aea98b/code/sites/all/modules/accuair_checkout/accuair_checkout.module(35): EntityStructureWrapper->__get('commerce_produc…’)
```

EDIT: I’ve tried loading the line items by IDs from the $order line item array. The following code does not produce any useful result (the information I want above).

```
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
  $order_lead_time = 0;
  $products = array();
  foreach ($order->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item) {
     $line_item = commerce_line_item_load($line_item[0]['line_item_id']);
     $line_item_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_line_item', $line_item);
     // no data here
```

Comment: It might be that you have shipping line items in there (which don't have a `commerce_product` field), so trying to access it will raise an exception. Try checking `$line_item_wrapper->type->value()` before you access that member. I think it'll just be 'product' for product items

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm not concerned about the error as much as I'm concerned about the data/fields for those products not being there. Would I need to use EntityQueries to accomplish something like this?

Comment: Try to use: `$line_item_wrapper->getBundle()` instead of `$line_item_wrapper->type->value()` as it could cause some issues like `Unable to get the data property type as the parent data structure is not set`.